# Angular2 - rendering component on demand and append in body

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

Im trying to create a plugin that takes a component as argument and render its content in the end of body tag. Just like the plugins that work with jQuery.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'some-selector',
    template: 'This is FirstComponent'
})
class FirstComponent{}

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: 'The root component'
})
class AppComponent{
    // ImaginaryModalOpener is what i want to achieve.
    // a standalone function that can take a component and render it in dom    
    // at the bottom of the body tag
    ImaginaryModalOpener(FirstComponent);
}
```

I have seen a lot of stackoverflow questions about rendering a dynamic components but they use directives or HTML markup in the root Component to start with.
In my case the Root template will have no directives or components for ImaginaryModalOpener.

Please point out if i've missed something.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44853707/2545680) should give you the solution, it doesn't user view container ref but instead uses direct DOM node to insert a component into

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get `ViewContainerRef` from `AppComponent` [how to get root viewContainerRef of angular2 aplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37660584/how-to-get-root-viewcontainerref-of-angular2-aplication)

and add a component to this `ViewContainerRef` like for example shown in  [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468)

The added component will be added as sibling to `AppComponent`. If `AppComponent` is a child of `<body>`, the dynamically added component will also be a child of `<body>`.

Comment: Thanks!, i finally came up with this code, appends the component to the body. Cheers.
    let factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(options.component);
    let newNode = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(newNode);
    const ref: any = factory.create(this.injector, [], newNode);
    this.app.attachView(ref.hostView);

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `Renderer2` on demand from a `RendererFactory2` and use this to add to `document.body`.

I needed to add an `iframe` for a third party tracking API that needed me to put an `iframe` on the page when the user made a purchase. So this example logically belongs in a service and not a component - it just so happens that the implementation results in a DOM element being added.

Inject these (even if `providerIn: 'root'`) :

```
 private rendererFactory: RendererFactory2,
 @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document
```

Then to create an iFrame:

```
createIFrame(url: string)
{
    const iframe: HTMLIFrameElement = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.src = url;
    iframe.width = '100';
    iframe.height = '100';
    iframe.frameBorder = '1';

    const renderer = this.rendererFactory.createRenderer(null, null);
    renderer.appendChild(this.document.body, iframe);
}
```

That's it. No messing around with `AppComponent` or `ViewReference` etc. - this is basically just pure Javascript in Angular form.