# Get AppComponent ViewContainerRef

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am looking for a way to get the `AppComponent` `ViewContainerRef` from a service.

I have found code online such as [this code](https://medium.com/@caroso1222/angular-pro-tip-how-to-dynamically-create-components-in-body-ba200cc289e6), [this code](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/dynamically-add-components-to-the-dom-with-angular-71b0cb535286) or [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9293#issuecomment-261329089), but they all are for previous versions of Angular (I am using version 6).

I would like to get this reference without having to set it myself through a setter.

Right now, I have to inject `ViewContainerRef` into `AppComponent` and give it to the service.

I would like to get the reference from nothing but an injected provider directly in the service, something along the lines of

```
  constructor(
    private applicationRef: ApplicationRef
  ) {
    this.viewContainerRef = applicationRef.getAppViewRef();
  }
```

The use-case is to create components and append them to the document, at body level or `AppComponent` level ; this would allow me to create notifications, dialogs ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I can't close my question, I am answering it.

For those that look for something similar [Thoughtram's Dominic Elm](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2017/11/20/custom-overlays-with-angulars-cdk.html) made a very good example of use of CDK's `Overlay`s and `Portals`.

Instead of looking for a reference to the root component, I'm going to append components dynamically to the application through that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use it exactly like in the link you provided. I created a stackblitz here: https://angular-5lhjkq.stackblitz.io In the *AppService* I inject the `ApplicationRef` and with `attachView`I add a *DummyComponent* in *AppComponent* to the body to and to the angular app.

This works seems to work exactly like in past versions.

Comment: The last part of that is setting me off : `const element =
      (newComponentInstance.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>)
        .rootNodes[0] as HTMLElement;

    document.body.appendChild(element);`. This doesn't seem natural and it isn't what's exposed in [the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader#resolving-components). That's why I was asking for another way, in Angular 6, using the `ViewContainerRef`.

Comment: I found this, but I am not sure if it still works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37660584/how-to-get-root-viewcontainerref-of-angular2-aplication